# Drupal 6 translation - Body, Title built-in interface

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, translation

I use i18n and I10n_client to translate English to Dutch in my web page, however some interface variables are not changing.

I searched 'Body' and tried to replace it with its Dutch word, but it doesn't take effect no matter what I do
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/831/searchbody1.png/

and
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/576/searchbody2.png

How can I change this type of built in interfaces? I can't change "Title" as well :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dutch is enough for me so I change the problematic labels to Dutch directly in the Edit content type form (go to Admin -> Content -> Content types, select edit for the one you want to change). 
By setting a Title and Body label in the "Submission form settings" fieldset.

There is a bug report open for this, see http://drupal.org/node/1016006

Answer (score 0):

you can download the translation file from
http://localize.drupal.org/
and import it in site_name/admin/build/translate/import
I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a german/chinese/english site. This is what helped for me

- A very helpfull module is [translation table](http://drupal.org/project/translation_table). A perfect
  table to do mass translation of
  content types, cck taxonomy and menus
- Goto /admin/build/translate/refresh
  to recreate missing strings